# How to count Matrix rows that are not empty?

Tags: templates, matrix, pixelandtonic

This seems like it should be a piece of cake, but I'm at a loss.

I have a Matrix field called {the_matrix} which contains two columns {comment} and {image}.  And I'm attempting to output the number of images like so:  **Total Images: 4**

The {total_rows} tag is not sufficient on its own because oftentimes there may be a {comment} and no {image}.  So essentially, I need to output the number of rows in which the {image} cell is not empty.

I have tried several different things (including the snippets below) to output the number of rows that contain an {image}, but have had no luck.

```
{the_matrix}
    Total Images: {image}{total_rows}{/image}
{/the_matrix}


{the_matrix}
    Total Images: {image}{field_row_count}{/image}
{/the_matrix}


{the_matrix}
    Total Images: {image:total_rows}
{/the_matrix}
```

Am I missing something obvious or am I just out of luck?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just attach a filter on the image column to check it isn't empty:

```
Total Images: {the_matrix:total_rows search:image="not IS_EMPTY"}
```

Comment: Thank you Ian! Your solution works perfectly. I never imagined that the :total_rows tag could work that way. Makes me wonder how many other functionalities I'm missing with Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using the Increment (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/increment) plugin like:

```
{the_matrix}
{if image}
{exp:pvl_increment id="image_count" random}
{/if}
{/the_matrix}
```

and find the total number of images:

```
{if {exp:pvl_increment id="image_count" increment="no" random} > 10}
[output]
{/if}
```

I hope, it would help you.

Comment: Thank you Bhashkar. Your solution looks like it would work just fine, but I think Ian's approach is a bit more direct.  I really appreciate your tip though, because I was not familiar with that add-on until you mentioned it. Cheers!